# How to get an object array behind a keyPath in AlamofireObjectMapper?

Tags: swift, alamofire, objectmapper

The server I connect to always returns its data objects behind the 'data' key, like this (hugely simplified):

```
{
    "data" : [ { "id" : 1,
                 "name" : "howdy"
               },
               { "id" : 2,
                 "name" : "dowdy"
               }
             ]
}
```

Now, I want to use Alamofire's ObjectMapper 4 to map the objects (with id, name) in the array to their proper Mappable objects.
However, I cannot find any sample code or explanation as to how to get the array behind the 'data' keyPath. Lot's of examples for arrays at the root level of the json.

Do I have to create a separate mappable object with a 'data' mapping and chain the array mapping from there?

Do I have to create an extension to DataRequest with my own ResponseObject and a filled-in keyPath?

Basically: how do I set the keyPath on the ResponseObject from the default nil to *anything*? Something like:

```
        .responseArray { response(keyPath:"data"): DataResponse<NameModel> in
```

This seems such a simple and common problem that it baffles me that I cannot find any samples :-/

Comment: Doesn't the `KeyPath` section [in the documentation](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper#keypath) do exactly this?

Comment: Yes it does indeed. I updated with an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, in hindsight, extremely easy. So easy that no-one ever bothered to make an example out of it, so here goes:

The keyPath has a default initialiser of nil. To use your own keyPath, you have to add the keyPath to the responseArray like this:

```
   .responseArray(keyPath: "data") { (response: DataResponse<[NameModel]>) in
        switch response.result {
            case .success(let items):
                var names: [NameModel] = []
                for name in items {
                    names.append(name)
                }
                completion(nil, names)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                self.handleError(error)
                completion(ServiceError.jsonError, nil)
                break
            }
```

I hope this helps anyone else who keeps looking at the documentation and thinks: how?